# convert Unix epoch timestamps to JavaScript date timestamps

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I have a database with Unix epoch timestamps and I would like to plot these values in a Highcharts chart, which requires JavaScript date timestamps (milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970).

The database array currently looks like this:

```
data: [[1519395624,100],[1519395804,100],[1519395984,178],
```

The converted array would look like this:

```
data: [[1519395624000,100],[1519395804000,100],[1519395984000,178],
```

What is the best way to do this?  Possible options:
   (1) multiply each database element by 1000
   (2) multiply the timestamp in PHP when I read the database row
   (3) multiply the timestamp in a Highcharts formatter function

I think converting the timestamp while I am reading the database row in PHP is the best approach.  My PHP looks like this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $rows['data'][]=$row;
    }
```

How should I change the while loop to multiply the timestamp (first element) in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $row[0] = $row[0] * 1000; 
    $rows['data'][]=$row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading the database row in PHP just to transfer the data to the client, and you're not using the given `timestamp` anywhere else in your PHP code, consider conversion right in your SQL request like:

`SELECT field, oter_field, timestamp * 1000 as timestamp ... FROM ...`

So you don't need to pollute your PHP or JS code with conversion.

In another case (if you need that timestamp to be used somewhere else in PHP), it would be better to convert the timestamp right before sending it to the client-side.